# How to make Chicago Manual Style - Notes and Bibliography style work?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

probably this is a easy question to answer but I'm just learning how to work with texstudio and latex. Currently I'm writing my thesis and I have to use chicago Manual Style - Notes and bibliography style. So the first citation with \footnote has to give me a full citation and the second time a shortened footnote citation. In the end I need the full bibliography printed (\printbibliography). I'm using biblatex and biber in Miktex. With the current package I have, I only get full citations in the footnotes and not a second shortened footnote... Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

This is an example of the declaration of my packages:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-notes]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../ref/mijnbibliografie.bib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{../LaTeX/Packages/boxedminipage/boxedminipage}
\usepackage[big, pagestyles]{../LaTeX/Packages/titlesec/titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should load the `biblatex-chicago` styles via the dedicated `biblatex-chicago` package. Use

```
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

instead of `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-notes]{biblatex}`.

If you load the style via its package, some options are set for you; amongst those are the options for citetracking, which are otherwise disabled by default.
The options set for the `note` style are

```
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    pagetracker=true,autocite=footnote,abbreviate=false,alldates=comp,
    citetracker=true,ibidtracker=constrict,usetranslator=true,
    usenamec=true,loccittracker=constrict,dateabbrev=false,
    maxbibnames=10,minbibnames=7,sorting=cms,sortcase=false}
```